# Use ES6 reduce or map to compute sums and percentages in nested objects of an Array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reduce

Apologies if the title is not particularly clear. I have made a short reproducible example below of what I'm attempting to do:

```
var arrayOfPeopleStats = [
  person1 = { 
    this: { makes: 10, attempts: 15, pct: .666667 },
    that: { makes: 12, attempts: 16, pct: .75 },
    thos: { value: 10, rank: 24 },
    them: { value: 15, rank: 11 }
  },
  person2 = { 
    this: { makes: 5, attempts: 15, pct: .333333 },
    that: { makes: 10, attempts: 12, pct: .83333 },
    thos: { value: 4, rank: 40 },
    them: { value: 3, rank: 32 }
  },
  person3 = { 
    this: { makes: 14, attempts: 14, pct: 1 },
    that: { makes: 7, attempts: 8, pct: .875 },
    thos: { value: 12, rank: 12 },
    them: { value: 13, rank: 10 }
  }
]


var desiredOutput = [
  allPeople: {
    this: { makes: 29, attempts: 44, pct: .65909 },
    that: { makes: 29, attempts: 36, pct: .80555 },
    thos: { value: 26, rank: doesnt matter },
    them: { value: 31, rank: doesnt matter }
  }
]
```

`arrayOfPeopleStats` is an array with person objects. Each person objects has a couple of stats (this, that thos, them, in this example), and each of those stats is an object with either the trio of `makes, attempts, steals`, or `value, rank`.

I would like to sum the makes, attempts, and values over the stat objects for each person, and compute the new `pct` value for the summed-together data.

I will post shortly on the attempt I've done using ES6 reduce, although I'm not sure this is the best approach for the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated on this!

Comment: _"Apologies if the title is not particularly clear"_  it could not actually be clearer 

Comment: Your `person1 = `, `person2 = `, etc statements are unnecessary (unless you're actually using those variables elsewhere)

Comment: According to me, you have to use map function to convert the array to a different array. In map, you could do something like this `arr.map((person) => { for key of person, perform reduce` and inside reduce, you could accumulate values corresponding to the `key` property and return the mapped element for the new array

Comment: This is very, very simple with a `forEach()` statement. Is there an absolute requirement to us map/reduce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will help you to start thinking about your data in terms of *types*.

a `Person` is an object with four properties,

1. `this` which is a `Stat` object (which we'll define soon)
2. `that` which is another `Stat` object
3. `thos` which is a `Rank` object (which we'll define as well)
4. `them` which is another `Rank` object

To continue, we specify `Stat` as an object with three properties,

1. `makes` which is a number
2. `attempts` which is another number
3. `pct` which is another number

And lastly, `Rank` is an object with two properties,

1. `value` which is a number
2. `rank` which is another number

We can now regard `arrayOfPeopleStats` as an array of items where each item is of type *Person*. To combine like types, we define a way to `create` values of our type and a way to `concat` (add) them.

I'll start by defining the smaller types first, `Stat` -

```
const Stat =
  { create: (makes, attempts) =>
      ({ makes, attempts, pct: makes / attempts })

  , concat: (s1, s2) =>
      Stat .create
        ( s1.makes + s2.makes
        , s1.attempts + s2.attempts
        )
  }
```

The `Rank` type is similar. You said it *"doesn't matter"* what the combined value for `rank` is, but this shows you that a choice *must* be made. You can pick one or the other, add the two values together, or some other option entirely. In this implementation, we choose the highest `rank` value -

```
const Rank =
  { create: (value, rank) =>
      ({ value, rank })

  , concat: (r1, r2) =>
      Rank .create
        ( r1.value + r2.value
        , Math .max (r1.rank, r2.rank)
        ) 
  }
```

Lastly, we implement `Person`. I renamed `this`, `that`, `thos`, `them` to `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` because `this` is a special variable in JavaScript and I think it makes the example a little easier to follow; the data in your question looks mocked anyway. What's important to note here is that the `Person.concat` function relies on `Stat.concat` and `Rank.concat`, keeping the combination logic for each type nicely separated -

```
const Person =
  { create: (a, b, c, d) =>
      ({ a, b, c, d })

  , concat: (p1, p2) =>
      Person .create
        ( Stat .concat (p1.a, p2.a)
        , Stat .concat (p1.b, p2.b)
        , Rank .concat (p1.c, p2.c)
        , Rank .concat (p1.d, p2.d)
        )
  }
```

Now to combine all `person` items in your array, simply reduce using the `Person.concat` operation -

```
arrayOfPeopleStat .reduce (Person.concat)

// { a: { makes: 29, attempts: 44, pct: 0.6590909090909091 }
// , b: { makes: 29, attempts: 36, pct: 0.8055555555555556 }
// , c: { value: 26, rank: 40 }
// , d: { value: 31, rank: 32 }
// }
```

Note, when you have nicely defined data constructors, writing the data out by hand using `{ ... }` is cumbersome and error prone. Instead use the `create` function of your type -

```
var arrayOfPeopleStat =
  [ Person .create
      ( Stat .create (10, 15)
      , Stat .create (12, 16)
      , Rank .create (10, 24)
      , Rank .create (15, 11)
      )
  , Person .create
      ( Stat .create (5, 15)
      , Stat .create (10, 12)
      , Rank .create (4, 40)
      , Rank .create (3, 32)
      )
  , Person .create
      ( Stat .create (14, 14)
      , Stat .create (7, 8)
      , Rank .create (12, 12)
      , Rank .create (13, 10)
      )
  ]
```

An added advantage of using `create` functions over writing out data by-hand using `{ ... }` is the constructors can do favors for you. Note how `pct` is automatically computed for `Stat`. This prevents someone from writing an invalid stat like `{ makes: 1, attempts: 2, pct: 3 }` where the `pct` property is not equal to `makes/attempts`. If the receiver of this data doesn't check, we have no way of ensuring the `pct` property's integrity. Using our constructor on the other hand, `Stat.create` only accepts `makes` and `attempts` and the `pct` field is automatically computed, guaranteeing a correct `pct` value.

The constructor could also prevent someone from creating an stat which would result in an error, such as `Stat .create (10, 0)` which would attempt to compute `10/0` (division by zero error) for the `pct` property -

```
const Stat =
  { create: (makes = 0, attempts = 0) =>
      attempts === 0
        ? { makes, attempts, pct: 0 }                // instead of throwing error
        : { makes, attempts, pct: makes / attempts } // safe to divide

  , concat: ...
  }
```

Ultimately these choices are up to you. Another programmer might favor an error in this situation. Such as -

```
Stat .create (10, 0)
// Error: invalid Stat. makes (10) cannot be greater than attempts (0). attempts cannot be zero.
```

The result of the `reduce` is the same, of course -

```
arrayOfPeopleStat .reduce (Person.concat)

// { a: { makes: 29, attempts: 44, pct: 0.6590909090909091 }
// , b: { makes: 29, attempts: 36, pct: 0.8055555555555556 }
// , c: { value: 26, rank: 40 }
// , d: { value: 31, rank: 32 }
// }
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const Stat =
  { create: (makes, attempts) =>
      ({ makes, attempts, pct: makes / attempts })

  , concat: (s1, s2) =>
      Stat .create
        ( s1.makes + s2.makes
        , s1.attempts + s2.attempts
        )
  }

const Rank =
  { create: (value, rank) =>
      ({ value, rank })
  
  , concat: (r1, r2) =>
      Rank .create
        ( r1.value + r2.value
        , Math .max (r1.rank, r2.rank)
        ) 
  }

const Person =
  { create: (a, b, c, d) =>
      ({ a, b, c, d })

  , concat: (p1, p2) =>
      Person .create
        ( Stat .concat (p1.a, p2.a)
        , Stat .concat (p1.b, p2.b)
        , Rank .concat (p1.c, p2.c)
        , Rank .concat (p1.d, p2.d)
        )
  }

var data =
  [ Person .create
      ( Stat .create (10, 15)
      , Stat .create (12, 16)
      , Rank .create (10, 24)
      , Rank .create (15, 11)
      )
  , Person .create
      ( Stat .create (5, 15)
      , Stat .create (10, 12)
      , Rank .create (4, 40)
      , Rank .create (3, 32)
      )
  , Person .create
      ( Stat .create (14, 14)
      , Stat .create (7, 8)
      , Rank .create (12, 12)
      , Rank .create (13, 10)
      )
  ]

console .log (data .reduce (Person.concat))

// { a: { makes: 29, attempts: 44, pct: 0.6590909090909091 }
// , b: { makes: 29, attempts: 36, pct: 0.8055555555555556 }
// , c: { value: 26, rank: 40 }
// , d: { value: 31, rank: 32 }
// }
```

---

But what happens if `data` is an empty array?

```
[] .reduce (Person.concat)
// Uncaught TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value
```

If a piece of our code works for some arrays but breaks for other arrays, that's bad. An array is used to represent *zero* or more values, so we want to cover all of our bases, including the case of zero stats. A function that is defined for *all* possible values of its input is a [total function](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/334874/99394) and we strive to write our programs this way whenever possible.

The error message provides the wisdom for the fix; we must provide the *initial value*. Such as `0` in -

```js
const add = (x, y) =>
  x + y

console .log
  ( [] .reduce (add, 0)           // 0
  , [ 1, 2, 3 ] .reduce (add, 0)  // 6
  )
```

Using the initial value, we always received a proper result, even when the array was empty. For adding numbers, we use the initial value of zero, because it is the [identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element). You can think of this as a sort of *empty* value.

If we're trying to `reduce` an array of Person types, what is the initial value for Person?

```
arrayOfPeopleStat .reduce (Person.concat, ???)
```

We define the an *empty* value for each of our types, if possible. We'll start with `Stat` -

```
const Stat = 
  { empty:
      { makes: 0
      , attempts: 0
      , pct: 0
      }
  , create: ...
  , concat: ...
  }
```

Next we'll do `Rank` -

```
const Rank =
  { empty:
      { value: 0
      , rank: 0
      }
  , create: ...
  , concat: ...
  }
```

Again, we're seeing the Person as *compound data*, ie data constructed of other data. We rely on `Stat.empty` and `Rank.empty` to create `Person.empty` -

```
const Person =
  { empty:
      { a: Stat.empty
      , b: Stat.empty
      , c: Rank.empty
      , d: Rank.empty
      }
  , create: ...
  , concat: ...
  }
```

Now we can specify `Person.empty` as the initial value and prevent aggravating errors from popping up -

```
arrayOfPeopleStat .reduce (Person.concat, Person.empty)
// { a: { makes: 29, attempts: 44, pct: 0.6590909090909091 }
// , b: { makes: 29, attempts: 36, pct: 0.8055555555555556 }
// , c: { value: 26, rank: 40 }
// , d: { value: 31, rank: 32 }
// }

[] .reduce (Person.concat, Person.empty)
// { a: { makes: 0, attempts: 0, pct: 0 }
// , b: { makes: 0, attempts: 0, pct: 0 }
// , c: { value: 0, rank: 0 }
// , d: { value: 0, rank: 0 }
// }
```

As a bonus, you now have a basic understanding of [monoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid).

Comment: Damn, this is an entire approach to coding that never crossed my mind, really appreciate the long and thorough solution.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'm happy you enjoyed it. I made a [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55155663/revisions) that includes an extra remark about the added usefulness of the `create` functions.

Answer (score 1):

When deciding between `map` and `reduce` you can think that `map` will return a new `array` with **same length of original one**. It isn't what you want, so you must not use it. You actually want to reduce your array to an object. So just use `reduce`:

About a function to reduce it, here is a possible one:

```js
var arrayOfPeopleStats=[person1={this:{makes:10,attempts:15,pct:.666667},that:{makes:12,attempts:16,pct:.75},thos:{value:10,rank:24},them:{value:15,rank:11}},person2={this:{makes:5,attempts:15,pct:.333333},that:{makes:10,attempts:12,pct:.83333},thos:{value:4,rank:40},them:{value:3,rank:32}},person3={this:{makes:14,attempts:14,pct:1},that:{makes:7,attempts:8,pct:.875},thos:{value:12,rank:12},them:{value:13,rank:10}}];

const resp = Object.values(arrayOfPeopleStats).reduce((obj, { this: localThis, that, thos, them }) => {
  obj.this = { makes: obj.this.makes + localThis.makes, attempts: obj.this.attempts + localThis.attempts };
  obj.this.pct = obj.this.makes / obj.this.attempts;
  obj.that = { makes: obj.that.makes + that.makes, attempts: obj.that.attempts + that.attempts };
  obj.that.pct = obj.that.makes / obj.that.attempts;
  obj.thos = { value: obj.thos.value + thos.value, rank: obj.thos.rank + thos.rank };
  obj.them = { value: obj.them.value + them.value, rank: obj.thos.rank + them.rank };
  return obj;
})

const formattedResp = [{ allPeople: resp }]

console.log(formattedResp)
```

And I don't suggest you using `this` as a property name once it can conflict with `this` keyword.

Comment: The reason this feels suffocating is because there is no separation of concerns. The reader cannot glance at the `reduce` lambda and understand its intention. See my answer for another approach that allows your program to grow in a more manageable way.

Answer (score -1):

```
arrayOfPeopleStats.reduce((a, v) => {
  a.allPeople.this = {
    makes: a.allPeople.this.makes + v.this,
    attempts: a.allPeople.this.attempts + v.this.attempts,
  };
  a.allPeople.that = {
    makes: a.allPeople.that.makes + v.that.makes,
    attempts: a.allPeople.that.attempts + v.that.attempts,
  };
  a.allPeople.thos = {
    value: a.allPeople.thos.value + v.thos.value,
  };
  a.allPeople.them = {
    value: a.allPeople.them.value + v.them.value,
  };
  a.allPeople.this.pct = a.allPeople.this.makes / a.allPeople.this.attempts
  a.allPeople.that.pct = a.allPeople.that.makes / a.allPeople.that.attempts
  return a;
}, {allPeople: {
    this: { makes: 0, attempts: 0, pct: 0 },
    that: { makes: 0, attempts: 0, pct: 0 },
    thos: { value: 0, rank: 0 },
    them: { value: 0, rank: 0 }
  }
}});
```

I have ignored rank as you have said it does not matter, it will be 0 always with the above solution. I have also chosen to not wrap the resulting object in an array as you have done in your desired result. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce for an explanation of this API.